# Get data from component in VueJS

Tags: vue.js

Lets say I have a template that contains another vue component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <custom-vue></custom-vue>
    </div>
</template>
```

And in my CustomVue script I have:

```
<script>
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            dataToExtract: "Access this"
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

How can I access the `dataToExtract` from outside of my CustomVue. If not possible, how could I achieve similar behavior.

Comment: Where exactly do you need to send dataToExtract?  In the parent component? In some unrelated component? Outside of Vue altogether?

Comment: In general, you _should not_ access `data` items from outside the component. The data should be owned by a parent that contains all of the components that need the data and be passed as a prop to them. Or use a store like Vuex.

Answer (score 0):

If the `<custom-vue></<custom-vue>` component is a child component of the template you are showing, then you have to access the data through `props` in the child component.

```
<script>
export default {
    props: ['data']
}
</script>
```

To give the child component these data you have to give it through the component tag like so:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <custom-vue :data="dataToExtract"></custom-vue>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
                dataToExtract: "Access this"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Remember that is is a unidirectional dataflow, so you wont be able to change the data state from the child with this.

A better way to share data states across components is Vuex.

I hope this will help you. For further documentation visit: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props